# If $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n \ dx=0$ for odd natural numbers, then $f\equiv 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f(x)$ is continuous.

I know the proof when this is true for all $n$. But I don't know how to proceed when it is only talking about odd $n$'s.

Comment: Hint. Substitute $u=x^2$.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right approach, but maybe integration by parts can show the antiderivative of $f$ is constant hence $f=0$.

Comment: Set $-x=y$ and find $$\int_{-1}^1f(x)x^n\ dx$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other words,
$$\int_0^1 x^{2k+1}f(x)\,dx=0$$
for all integers $k\ge0$. Therefore
$$\int_0^1 xf(x)g(x^2)\,dx=0$$
for all polynomials $g$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, the polynomials
of the form $g(x^2)$ are dense in the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$
under the supremum metric. That is, given a continuous $h$ on $[0,1]$, there
is a sequence of polynomials $g_n$ such that $g_n(x^2)\to h(x)$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Take $h(x)=xf(x)$. Then $g_n(x^2)\to xf(x)^2$ uniformly  and $xf(x)g_n(x^2)\to(xf(x))^2$ uniformly too. Therefore
$$0=\int_0^1 xf(x)g_n(x^2)\,dx\to\int_0^1 (xf(x)^2)\,dx$$
and so this last integral is zero. As $f$ is continuous, this
means that $f$ is zero on $[0,1]$.